# Get a value of column for which there may be or not be an entry present in previously joined tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here's the query I want to write...

```
SELECT top 10 U.userid, U.fullname, U.username, T.tid, T.msg, T.tpic, T.ttime, COUNT(R.tid)
FROM USER_DETAILS AS U
INNER JOIN TWEET AS T ON U.userid = T.tuid
LEFT OUTER JOIN RETWEET AS R ON T.tuid = R.tid
WHERE (T.tuid IN (SELECT f.fuid FROM FOLLOW AS F WHERE F.userid = @usrid) OR T.tuid = @usrid)
ORDER BY T.ttime DESC;
```

I know the query is wrong because of aggregation. All I want is the count of the tweets being retweeted. So what is the better way of doing this?

The tables are :

```
User_details(userid, fullname, username)

Follow(userid, fuid) where userid is following fuid

Tweet(tid, tuid)

Retweet(tid, ruid) where ruid is the user doing the retweet.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be useful if you explain how you know it is wrong and what you know is wrong with it, so I can be confident that all of your issues have been addressed. However, immediately obvious is that you don't have a group by clause, which you need for the aggregation to work.

```
SELECT top 10 U.userid, U.fullname, U.username, T.tid, T.msg, T.tpic, T.ttime, COUNT(R.tid)
FROM USER_DETAILS AS U
INNER JOIN TWEET AS T ON U.userid = T.tuid
LEFT OUTER JOIN RETWEET AS R ON T.tuid = R.tid
WHERE (T.tuid IN (SELECT f.fuid FROM FOLLOW AS F WHERE F.userid = @usrid) OR T.tuid = @usrid)
GROUP BY U.userid, U.fullname, U.username, T.tid, T.msg, T.tpic, T.ttime
ORDER BY T.ttime DESC;
```

Comment: While trying the group by clause, I was writing only R.tid. Thus, this error 'Column 'USER_DETAILS.userid' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause'. My silly mistake.. Thank you very much! :)